# Does index.js slowdown Nodejs when loading

Tags: node.js, performance, import, routes

My NodeJS app is taking a long time (30 seconds) to load and reload on every change with nodemon. I have 15 utils and 35 routes. I have a utils/index.js and routes/index.js file that imports and exports everything within those respective folders.

I suspect the index.js files may be causing the app to load and import/export all files at once which may somehow be slowing it down when starting up.

Question: Does having an index.js slow down NodeJS? Is the way I'm loading my routes inefficient? Or is 30 seconds normal to start up an app of this size?

routes/route1.js

```js
export const route1 = (app) => {
  app.get('/route1', (req, res, next) => { ... }
}
```

routes/index.js

```js
// I'm using latest ES6 imports
import { route1 } from './route1';
// ...
import { route35 } from './route35';

export const route = (app) => {
  route1(app);
  // ...
  route35(app);
}
```

App.js

```js
// ...
import { routes } from 'routes/index';
routes(app);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having every route be in a file make them into a category in a file so the loading time drops and use https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router do not export functions just export the router obj so you will not have to execute the function